# How can I run prepareForSegue After didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get the `indexPath.row` that user clicked and then check with my array to return a String from that `indexPath.row` and then send the String via preparforSegue.... But it doesnt work. I think the program runs the preparForSegue BEFORE the `didselectRowatIndexPath`... How can I do this?

**My Code:**

```
import UIKit
import Parse


class CategoriaTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var queryArray: [PFObject] = [PFObject]()
var escolha = 5

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    var query = PFQuery(className:"Categorias")
    //querycomlocalidade
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) Restaurantes.")
            if let _objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

                self.queryArray = _objects
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        } else {
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return queryArray.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CategoriaTableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ceculaCategoria", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CategoriaTableViewCell


    let categoria = queryArray[indexPath.row] as! PFObject

    //Insere texto
    cell.tituloCecula.text = categoria.objectForKey("nome") as! String


    //Insere imagens no tableview
    if let categoriaImagem = categoria.objectForKey("imagem") as? PFFile {

        categoriaImagem.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                cell.imagemCecula.image = UIImage(data:imageData!)                }
        }
    }


    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    escolha = indexPath.row

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    var detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as! ListaTableViewController

    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
        let row = Int(indexPath.row)

        let categoriaEscolhida = queryArray[escolha] as PFObject

        //Insere texto

        detailScene.categoria = categoriaEscolhida.objectForKey("nome") as! String



    }

}



}
```

Comment: What if you ignore `escolha` and use `queryArray[row]`?

Comment: That way how do I know which row did he select?

Comment: Well... I don't know how, but it seems that its working. How is that possible? :) Row contains the Row that he clicked?

Comment: You know because you're calling `indexPathForSelectedRow`.

Comment: Row contains the index of the row.

Comment: How did I misses that... Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to right an answer so I can assign to you? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have linked the segue directly from your cell in the storyboard then `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` **will not execute before the segue is triggered**.

What you can do is create a segue by Ctrl-dragging from the view controller object in the storyboard to the destination scene and giving the segue an identifier as you would with any other segue. Delete the segue from your cell.

Now you can call `performSegueWithIdentifier` to trigger the segue and pass the object that was selected as the `sender`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   // tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)  // Optionally deselect the row for a cleaner appearance
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegueIdentifier", sender: queryArray[indexPath.row])
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if let detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as? ListaTableViewController {          
        let categoriaEscolhida = sender as! PFObject
        detailScene.categoria = categoriaEscolhida.objectForKey("nome") as! String

    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the segue between the two view controllers and trigger it manually:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    escolha = indexPath.row
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("push", sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    escolha = indexPath.row
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("push", sender: self)
}
```

Complete with ...

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:"push"]) {
    // Code
    }
```