# How to get value from table view cell

Tags: swift, tableview

I need to take price from table view cell
I need to get it another VC
I need to transfer price each time when user selected row
The problem is that I don't know how correctly get the value from tableView
MenueViewController:

```
import UIKit

class MenueViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

   var dishes: [Dish] = []

   var totalSum = 0

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       dishes = createArray()

       tableView.delegate = self
       tableView.dataSource = self
       tableView.backgroundColor = .white
       navigationItem.title = "Меню"

   }

   func createArray() -> [Dish] {

       var tempDishes: [Dish] = []

       let dish1 = Dish(image: UIImage.init(named: "plovKebab")!, title: "Плов Кебаб", price: 169, type: "Основные Блюда")
       let dish2 = Dish(image: UIImage.init(named: "plovKebabShafran")!, title: "Плов Кебаб Шафран", price: 169, type: "Основные Блюда")

       tempDishes.append(dish1)
       tempDishes.append(dish2)

       return tempDishes
   }

}
extension MenueViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return dishes.count
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let dish = dishes[indexPath.row]

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MenueCell") as! MenueCell
       cell.setDish(dish: dish)


       return cell
   }
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       let dish = dishes[indexPath.row]
       totalSum += dish.price //the place where I tried to take price
       print(totalSum)
   }
}
```

VC where we need to take that price:

```
import UIKit

class OrderViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var totalPriceLabel: UILabel!

   var totalPrice: MenueViewController?
   var sum:Int?
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       if let price = sum {

       totalPriceLabel.text = String(totalPrice?.totalSum)

       }
   }
```

The value of sum is 0
How can I get the value?

Comment: Shouldn't you get the price from the data source, `var dishes: [Dish]` instead?

Comment: Hi Fillsondy, how do you move to that other VC? From the MenuViewController to the OrderViewController?

Comment: I need to take the value of totalSum to my OrderVC, so for example user tapped 2 times at cell and change VC to OrderVC, its need to display totalSum of 2 cell value

Comment: Hi MacUserT, I use Present Modally segue. So user press button and change VC

Comment: So when the user tap on the sell you get the corresponding Dish object from your dishes array and use it to get  price/sum. My point here is that it is your data source you should work with and not UI components to get the correct values becuase it is you model `Dish` that holds the data..

Comment: As Joakim points out, the price dos NOT come from the tableview, it comes from the data source, and is presented in the tableview.  When you update the value through the tableview, you should update the data, but things become simpler if you stop thinking about the UI as being your data source

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift: Pass UITableViewCell label to new ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315133/swift-pass-uitableviewcell-label-to-new-viewcontroller)

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the `didSelectRowAtIndexpath` will not get called before your `performSegue`. At this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32257960/how-can-i-run-prepareforsegue-after-didselectrowatindexpath), you can find a detailed explanation including a sample code about your problem and how it can be solved.

Also, there are multiple approaches listed below to solve your problem.

- Use `willSelectIndexpath` and capture the indexpath to pass it in `performSegue` method
- Use `didSelectIndexpath` and perform segue inside
- Use only `didSelectIndexpath` and perform the navigation logic inside it with out segues